# Templating 2013 Dev environments in VMWare

Tags: 2013, development-enviroment

I am looking for a lean, minimal headache setup process for setting up SharePoint 2013 Enterprise development environments for my organization. We are using VMware and though we could use a template solution for our dev boxes. My thought was to use a typical single box setup with Visual Studio, AD and SQL on the same box with SharePoint. Another member has suggested only VS and SharePoint on the virtual and SQL and AD would be shared. 
How does your company spin up development environments using VMware? Do you share SQL or AD? Does this even make sense? I would think sharing SQL there'd be a performance hit and sharing AD there could be account lockout issues affecting other members. Any BPs, white papers or articles you can recommend?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For one of my customer I created a VM Template which has following

1. Windows Server
2. SQL Server
3. SharePoint Server
4. Visual Studio
5. Other developer tools like Designer, ULS viewer etc

AD is the company AD.

The only thing you need to make sure which creating the template is to make sure no machine specific information is written to the database and also make sure to generate new system ID's.

After installing SharePoint ensure "Run Configuration Wizard" later is checked. While creating VM you should run SysPrep.

Detailed information can be found in this link http://sharepointmentalnotes.blogspot.com/2011/07/creating-sharepoint-virtual-machine.html